# create new session everytime login success does not work properly in java servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have a jsp index page which contains 3 button (login as user, register, login as manager). Whenever user chose one of these option. it will redirect to a loginservlet (via http FORM) and from loginServlet i can check the login data and init new session if data is valid. However when i use SessionListener to check if a new session is created when new user registed or login, I always get the same session-id.

here is the function in loginServlet

```
    private void initSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String sessionsTyp) {
    // https://www.studytonight.com/servlet/httpsession.php
    // Create Session if user-login or manager-login success
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (sessionsTyp.equals("userLogin") || sessionsTyp.equals("managerLogin")) {
        if (sessionsTyp.equals("managerLogin")) {
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
        }
    } else {   // Create Session if registry success
        session = request.getSession(true);
    }
    // Storing user information in an attribute of Session. Username is unique therefore use username as sessionid
    if (this.username != null) {
        session.setAttribute(Constants.SESSION_USER_KEY, username);
    } else {
        session.setAttribute(Constants.SESSION_MANAGER_KEY, session.getId());
    }
}
```

when i open new index.jsp page in order to log in or registry, i do not get a new session (i can see it in the log). And one thing that i cant understand is when i start the server i immediately get a new session id.
I ḿ new in servlet. please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should call `session.invalidate()`, which basically discards the current session and unbinds any object bound to it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate()

Comment: I know this function. I also call this function when user click on log-out button on manager.jsp and user.jsp webpage. But the thinks here is, when i open new index.jsp and log in or create new user succesfully i need new session and with session.getSession() i always see in the log one session. so actually no new session was created